# Google Chrome vs jQuery .remove on Mac Mountain Lion

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Tested only one Mountain Lion (Mac), but when using Google Chrome and jQuery's .remove() the element is removed from the dom but not removed from the screen.

My css stops working on the removed  tag but the artifact of is left on the screen. I can't find anything on this with my searching.

Chrome Version 24.0.1312.57 - jQuery v1.7.1

Code so you can reproduce:

http://w2r.com/x/

NOTICE: The problem happens when you click remove on the last element.

Comment: Do you have any non-standard Chrome flags turned on? (Especially relating to, say, the GPU, or compositing.)

Comment: I can't say that this is an answer, but you're HTML is really quite bad. IDs must be unique and, if you're doctype isn't HTML5 then they also cannot start with a number. I've made a quick fiddle and I don't see any problems: http://jsfiddle.net/C7RGF/

Comment: minitech - good thought but I just had a friend test too same result. My chrome has no extentions and is unchanged from install as far as I know.

The HTML is fine for this example - I just recreated the actual project with dummy info that is unnecessary to reproduce the error-- however i did not realize it has a css element to actually cause the error. 

Please view my edited link to see the code , and the functionality.

http://www.w2r.com/x/ ----- NOTE Try removing the LAST element first.

Comment: @SirChuck please don't remove your code example from your question as this question will no longer contain all the relevant information. If you're removing the sample page from your website, other people will no longer be able to understand what this question was about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues in your code:

You should use unique ID's for all elements (as mentioned in the other answer)

ID's *must* start with a letter (a-z) in order to be valid

'spans' (inline elements) should *not* be the parent of 'divs' (block elements)

jQuery.live() is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and should no longer be used, use .on() instead

Use delegation (event bubbling) in stead of assigning event handlers on every element, this will make your code lighter, faster and (especially since you're *removing* elements from the dom, reduces the risk of memory leaks)

```
<div class='wrapper-div'>
  <div id="e6" class='day'>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="n_6" value="6" /><div>Label</div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remDay">Remove</a>
        </div>
  </div>
  <div id="e7" class='day'>
    <div>
      <input type="hidden" name="n_7" value="7" /><div>Label</div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remDay">Remove</a>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

 $('.wrapper-div').on('click', '.remDay', function() {
    $(this).closest('div.day').remove();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: ya, I upgraded to 1.9 to see if that would correct the issue , but it still does not. http://www.w2r.com/x/ you'll see the updated code. Using ID's that start with numbers also have no relivance to this particular issue, the spans are contained within a containing div. Please see http://www.w2r.com/x/ page source. I could change the id names if you really still think thats the issue, but it's not.

Comment: Looks like it is the <span> containing a <div> that was the issue.

Comment: @SirChuck Glad you were able to resolve the issue. The remarks I made are also to improve your skills and write better code. A good developer doesn't stop if things 'just' work, but also tries to improve himself and hits code. Producing 'valid' code and HTML reduces the risk of things stopping to work if a new browser version is released

Answer (score 0):

You must use unique ID tags for DOM elements.

Or use a different tag, like class, if you want to stick with "remDay".

```
....

<span id="ID6"><div><input type="hidden" name="n_6" value="6" /> <div >Label:</div> TEXT 
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remDay">Remove</a></div></span>

....

   $('.remDay').live('click', function() {
        $(this).parents('span').remove(); // Ticket #13359
   });
```

Also IDs must contain a letter as for http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Comment: Also, id's *must* start with a letter (a-z), otherwise they are invalid

Comment: In what browser do they need to start with a letter? Technically you are right, but to see the functionally of my issue using an id or a class does not matter when using the (this) operator. I did change the #remDay to .remDay in my http://www.w2r.com/x/ example so you could see that was not the issue.

Comment: @SirChuck browsers do a lot of work 'under the hood' to try to fix errors in the HTML (for example non-closed tags, invalid or duplicate id's). The fact that a browser was able to correct your errors doesn't mean your code is correct. Future versions of a browser may treat an error differently, causing your page to stop working